# Finding posterior distribution with theta in the exponential of the likelihood product

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, posterior

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. with common density $$f(x)=\theta x^{\theta -1}I\{x \in [0,1]\}$$ where $\theta >0$.
>
> (b) Put a prior distribution on $\theta$ which is exp($2$).  Obtain the posterior density function of $\theta$ given a sample $X_1,...,X_n$. Do you recognize this type of density function?

I'm stuck on this.  I know posterior is proportional to likelihood times prior.  I currently have the following:
$$f(\theta) \propto 2e^{-2\theta}\theta^{n}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{\theta-1}$$
From here I am stuck.  Any advice?

Comment: Please add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track! If we manipulate the posterior density a bit, we get:

$$f(\theta|x)\propto 2e^{-2\theta}\theta^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\theta-1}\\
\propto e^{-2\theta}\theta^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^{\theta-1}\\
\propto\theta^n\left(e^{-2}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^\theta$$

Which is proportional to [the Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), with parameters given by:
$\alpha=n+1$ and $\exp(-\beta)=e^{-2}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$ (or, equivalently, $\beta=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln x_i-2$).

Comment: omg that seems so obvious now that I'm looking at it haha.  thank you so much!